# How does JDK 7's support termination affect Android development

Tags: java, android

Oracle [has announced](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) that they stop the official updates for JRE 7 and [JDK 7](https://www.stsoftware.com.au/site/ST/blog/article/jdk7-end-of-life/).

*As much as I know*, Google doesn't say anything about JDK 8, I guess the recommended version is JDK 7 for Android development.

**Is JDK 8 officially supported for Android development?**

Comment: You could always adopt Groovy, which is fully supported on Android as of the 2.4 series.

Comment: Make up your mind. Either you know that Google doesn't support JDK 8 or you don't.

Comment: I don't see how "opinion" matters in this question

Comment: @RC. Please vote reopen then.

Comment: @RC., you'd have to look at the edit history to understand why it was closed. It used to be entirely opinion based. Now it's good and I too will vote to reopen it.

Comment: But it still doesn't make sense. Google supports what Google supports, and Oracle supports what Oracle supports, and Oracle certainly does not support Google in any way.

Comment: @EJP It doesn't matter if Oracle supports Google. Google should support JDK 8 as soon as possible... The question is regarding Google and it is a fair question (I can't rely on a non-supported Development Kit - and I reckon noone can)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Android development [page](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and, from there, the [pre-requisites page](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements) list JDK7 as a requirement.

This has nothing to do with Oracle's JRE since the code made during Android development is never meant to run on that JRE - it's supposed to be turned into Dalvik bytecode and run under Android.

So the security concerns of Oracle's JRE are not really at issue here. Google supports JDK7 (insomuch as it pertains to Android development) so *that's* what you should be using, pending a clear statement of intent from Google.

Comment: The issue at hand is not the JRE but the SDK itself - it is a key part of Android development so if Oracle stops fixing it, I need to consider if I want to (forced to?) use it anymore.

Comment: @Nestor, Google will support your use of it for Android development, Oracle have *never* supported it for anything even remotely related to Android. If you find a bug in the SDK and Oracle won't fix it (they'll hang up on you the second you mention Android), Google will have work around it.

Comment: Well, that is very sad. As maintainers of such huge ecosystems, they should work together in cases of bug fixing. I'll accept your reasoning, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google doesn't officially support the JDK 8 for Android development.  See paxdiablo's answer.

But let me add some thoughts.

I wanted to try using the JDK 8 anyway.  So I downloaded and installed it, and used it (and Apache Ant) to build a simple Android app.

The app doesn't use any features which are new to Java 8, such as lambdas.  In addition, Ant passed a parameter to `javac` asking it to emit bytecode compatible with older JREs.

The app compiled fine.

The app requires that I root my phone before running it. I haven't done so yet, and haven't tested the app yet either.